# Copy one cell to adjacent cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I have a formula in column Y. Because of the nature of the formula, I want to copy the contents of the data in column Y when the formula gets calculated, into column Z (onEdit). The code I have so far does not copy any data into the adjacent cell and does nothing when executed:

```
function onEdit(CopyCourse){

  if(CopyCourse.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
    var actcell = CopyCourse.source.getActiveCell();
    var col = CopyCourse.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
    if(col == 25) {
      var calcourse = CopyCourse.range.offset(0,1);   
      //if(calcourse.getValue() == "" && CopyCourse.value != "No") {
      var course = CopyCourse.actcell.getValue();
      calcourse.setValue(course);
      //}
    }
  }    

}
```

Newer attempt, again no action on the spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e){

var r = e.range();
var o = e.oldValue();
var n = e.range().offset(0,1);
n.setValue(o);
}
```

Comment: If you use the event object's `range` property (rather than erroneously reading from the current active cell), does this change anything? Also consider using the `value` and `oldValue` properties. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit
 - It's possible the formula is not evaluated before the edit event is sent (i.e. a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` call may be needed).

Comment: Still no luck. Nothing is getting copied into the new cell. I've updated my question with the new code, per your suggestions.

Comment: Note that the documentation clearly states that the event parameters `value` and `oldValue` are only available when a single cell is edited. If you are auto-filling a large range, that is more than a single cell, so `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are each `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It works if I enter the formula in each individual cell, however, if I do a copy down, it only copies over the first cell.

```
function onEdit(e){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var row = e.source.getActiveCell().getRow();
var col = e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
if(col == 25){
    var course = e.source.getActiveCell().getValue();
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row,col+1);
    cell.setValue(course);
}
```

}